# Get the value of the checkboxes after clicking the transmit button

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I have checkbox list and I am trying to get the result after the user selected **multiple chexkboxes** and  **clicked the `transmit` button**
how can I get the multiple checkboxes values after clicking the `trasmit` button?

I appreciate any help.

```
private void createRadioButton(final ArrayList<Integer> items) {

    final LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lila);
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
        cb.setText(items.get(i) + "");
        cb.setId(i);
        ll.addView(cb);

    }
    Button btn = new Button(this);
    btn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(500, 150));
    btn.setText("submit");
    ll.addView(btn);

}
```

Edit 1:

private void createRadioButton(final ArrayList items) {

```
    final LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lila);
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
        cb.setText(items.get(i) + "");
        cb.setId(i);
        ll.addView(cb);

    }
    Button btn = new Button(this);
    btn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(500, 150));
    btn.setText("submit");
    ll.addView(btn);
    //here I am getting this error: OnClickListener cannot be resolved to a type
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        for(int i: items){
             //here I am getting `cb cannot be resolved`
            if(cb.getId(i).isChecked()){

            }
        }

        }
    });


}
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html). You can just use `isChecked()` on a check box.  Just iterate over them using the ids that you are setting in your for loop.

Comment: but when I added the following `btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){}` I am getting the error `- OnClickListener cannot be resolved to a type
 - The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new ` then in the OnClickeListener I want iterate and check with `isChecked`